# Please assist with my code keep getting an variable sc error

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java program that prompts the user to enter a number well guess the number with a void method called `CheckNum (int num)` and the decision statements in the void method `CheckNum`, checks if the number entered is 100, if that is true, the following message “Number is correct!"

So far this is what I have created:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        checkNum();
    }

    public static void checkNum()
    {

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int guess= sc.nextInt();
        int number=(int)(Math.random()*100)+1;
        System.out.println("The number is "+number);
        if(guess>=1 && guess<=100)
        {
            if(guess==number)
                System.out.println("The number is right!");
            else
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Make it a 1-100 please!");
            checkNum();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Neo, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you post the error message as well?

Comment: The variable `sc` is out of scope, you can't simply use variable form other methods

Comment: cc is not in the checkNum scope. Either pass it to the function when you call it, or create cc inside the checkNum method.

Comment: Hi  @Sinan, the error that I was getting indicated: symbol variable sc, java cannot find symbol.

Comment: I tried the below suggestion and the program ran without errors

Answer (score 2):

You can't just use variable from other method. Here are options for you

- Define the `Scanner` as static for the class

  ```
  public class Main{
      static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      public static void main(String[] args){
          checkNum();
      }
      public static void checkNum(){...}
  }
  ```
- Pass the `Scanner` as a parameter

  ```
  public class Main{    
      public static void main(String[] args){
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          checkNum(sc);
      }
      public static void checkNum(Scanner sc){...}
  }
  ```
- Define it only in the method

  ```
  public class Main{    
      public static void main(String[] args){
          checkNum();
      }
      public static void checkNum(){
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @ Azro Thank you very much that cleared the error and the program ran